# Flutter location package is not working in background

Tags: flutter, dart, location, background-process

I am using flutter location package for tracking user location. It is working as expected.
Problem comes when I minimize app, it stops giving location data.

I want to continue getting location data even if app is minimized.

This is how I am getting users location.

```
Future<void> _listenLocation(store) async {
    print('listen 1');
    location.changeSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 20, interval: 5000);

    _locationSubscription =
        location.onLocationChanged.handleError((dynamic err) {
      setState(() {
        _error = err.code;
      });
      _locationSubscription.cancel();
    }).listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
      print('listen 2');
      setState(() {
        print('listen 3');
        _error = null;

        _location = currentLocation;


        print('_location');
        print(_location.speed);
        print(currentLocation.speed);


      });
    });

  }
```

I am new to flutter, please help.

Comment: Did you request for the permission to use location services?

Comment: yes. It is working when app is open.

added this in manifest file.

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: Any messages in the console related to the issue?

Comment: there is not issue. It just flutter location package is not working in background. I want to understand how can we get location even in background.

Comment: Try using the flutter_background_geolocation package. [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_geolocation).

Comment: Thanks for link. I have checked it but only issue is, this package is not free. We will have to buy licence for it.

Comment: Maybe this one then https://pub.dev/packages/background_location. You can look for packages on https://pub.dev/  by basically searching for what you want. Very easy to use, and very useful.

Answer (score 2):

On some Android versions, the normal location package keeps working. On others, however, it stops all code execution when the app is in the background (not the front-most app).

I had a bad experience with the [background_location](https://pub.dev/packages/background_location) package. The [carp_background_location](https://pub.dev/packages/carp_background_location) package seemed to work perfectly for me. It is build on top of the more complex [background_locator](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator) package, which probably also works fine.

I would recommend the [carp_background_location](https://pub.dev/packages/carp_background_location) package. It is simple to implement.